# Is Typescript != ES6?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I thought that Typescript supported all the new constructs of ES6. I was just playing with examples from http://www.2ality.com/2015/08/es6-map-json.html and for example,

`var a = new Map([[true, 7], [{foo: 3}, ['abc']]])`

Gives errors, lots of them. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Yes, Typescript is different from ES6, although it has incorporated many of the ES6 constructs.

Comment: Can you post the errors, please?

Comment: Also, make sure the compiler is targeting ES6. TypeScript doesn't do this by default. You can do this by setting the `--target` flag.

Comment: @mallison dont use `--target es6` unless the runtime supports all the es6 features that typescript at the moment ..... which at the time of this writing are none of `node`/`chrome`/`firefox`. So *Don't*

Comment: @basarat The question is about writing ES6, where it can be used or not is irrelevant. It could be sent through something Babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you'll need to write a .d.ts typing for it.

Here's one that is as simple as it gets to allow you to instantiate the class the way you would expect.

```
interface MapStatic {
    new(m: any): MapInstance;  /*Use 'any' if you don't want typing, 
                               and don't want to maintain the MapInstance */
}
interface MapInstance {
}
declare var Map: MapStatic;
```

Just in case you need it, [here's the guide.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files)

The [Typescript roadmap](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ECMAScript%206%20Status&referringTitle=Roadmap) says that Map is a complete feature. I'd double check to make sure you have the latest typescript installation. Get it through node.js with this install command:

> npm install -g typescript

Comment: Yes I did have the latest typescript, but didn't import the typing file for it. That's likely my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> but I thought that Typescript supported all the new constructs of ES6

Not all of them. See : https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ Specifically

Comment: That does answer the title of this question. But, as far as Map itself is concerned, which was my example, that is fully supported per the compat table.